# How do I write this formula's IF statement with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure how to write the formula for the result:

My formula is: `=IF(AND([@[Case Reason Reason Peanut ]]="True",[@Peanut]="False"),"True",IF([@[Share Contact ]]="False","Peanut"))`

I have in A1=False, B1=True and C1=False, the result needs to be Peanut

Then in A2=True, B2= False, C2=False, result needs to be Peanut

Then in A3=True, B3= True, C3=False, result needs to be Peanut

I  have a total of 3000 rows with false and true.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your results table, and assuming all other instances give no peanut response, then you want the word PEANUT only when either `[Case Reason Reason Peanut ]` is true or `[@Peanut]` is true, and `[Share Contact ]` is false.
We can produce this by nesting `OR` and `AND` selections. (I'm going to shorten my typing by using the A,B,C columns.

```
=IF(AND(OR(A1="True",B1="True"),C1="False"),"Peanut")
```